# How to move marker with mouse move on google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to move marker with mouse move in this example?

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html

Here marker is automatically animated after 50 ms but i want to move marker with mouse move on map.

Any idea on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Markers movement is done in `startAnimation()` and `animate()` functions. So, instead of calling `setTimeout()` you have to do it manually, I imagine with mouse event handlers connected to marker. For each mouse move you have to do similar processing. There is step 50 m but moving mouse you will have to calculate step and pan the map.

Comment: it is already moving but not with mouse move it is moving through animation. I want to move marker with mouse move. http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html something like this but marker should move on mouse move